Excel - How to compare cells of columns in different sheets
I have to compare two columns that are in different sheets of the same excel file, the columns have different lenghts and the cells contains dates formatted as: dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mm:ss
Let's call the first sheet Bob and the second Mary.
I need to compare month and year of each cell of the column with the dates in Bob with the cells of the column with the dates in Mary, and when i find a match copy the whole row corresponding to that date from Bob to a new sheet.
The dates columns in the two sheets are in different places, in Bob is in B and in Mary is in A
I don't have any idea on how to do this, I'm lost

Look into VLOOKUP, and INDEX/MATCH

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is not clear what the dates look like in the different sheets. Please edit your question and post a data sample of the dates for each of the sheets.
